# How to add popup or bind popup to a point/marker in Leaflet FlowMap without breaking the 'flow' display?

Tags: leaflet

I am using the following leaflet plugin:

https://github.com/jwasilgeo/Leaflet.Canvas-Flowmap-Layer

I am having issues adding a popup to the map when a user clicks on a point.

```
              L.marker([pts[p].lat, pts[p].lng], {
                  icon: new L.DivIcon({
                      html: '<div>Test</div>'
                  })
              }).addTo(map).bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
```

.openPopup();

The popup shows, but I am unable to get the actual flowmap lines to show up. Is there anyway to allow for a popup and to allow for the lines to show up underneath it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that the CanvasFlowmapLayer extends L.GeoJSON

You just need to overload the method creating the marker and add your popup there ...

```
    var oneToManyFlowmapLayer = L.canvasFlowmapLayer(geoJsonFeatureCollection, {
      pointToLayer: function(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
        var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng);
         return marker.bindPopup('' + latlng)
      },
      // et caetera
```

Check it out here: https://yafred.github.io/Leaflet.Canvas-Flowmap-Layer/docs/main/